# Limit question difference between $n^2/n$ and $n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Here is a possibly VERY naive question about limits from someone who doesn't know much calculus. What is the difference between the limit of $n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and the limit of $\large{\frac{n^2}{n}}$ as ${n \rightarrow \infty}$. Are they both infinity?

Comment: absolutely none.  They're both $\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n - \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n^2}n$$ doesn't make sense since both the limits are $\infty$'s and it doesn't make sense to perform naive algebraic operations on $\infty$.

However,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(n - \dfrac{n^2}n\right) = 0$$ since $\left(n - \dfrac{n^2}n\right)= 0 $ for all $n \neq 0$.

Note that clearly both are different quantities.

Comment: Sorry, my question was phrased badly, I didn't mean difference as in subtraction, but difference as in "are the two limits different". I thought that maybe as $\frac{\infty^2}{\infty}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ which is undefined. Do you simplify the expression before you "plug in" infinity???